# Adding datas into an array to list in another activity

Tags: android, arrays, listview, android-studio, apk

Below are the 3 java classes that I am using for my android application development. I would like to add the student data (name and phone number) from the AddActivity to be stored in MainActivity page after clicking "Add". I have researched on this and tried using an array but I am quite confused on how the logic must be for the code to send the datas keyed in AddActivity into the MainActivity page. Can anyone give me a guidance on how to work this out and would really be grateful if you could show me another way rather the way I am trying. I want the data to be stored in a ListView format in the MainActivity after each "Add" I have clicked in the AddActivity page. Do hope that someone will be able to guide me in doing this. Thank you.

MainActivity.java - https://jsfiddle.net/eb1fprnn/

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listView;
Button addStudent;
ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    add();
}



public void add() {
    Student student;
    addStudent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    addStudent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

AddActivity.java - https://jsfiddle.net/40k5mas2/

```
public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText name, phone;
Button add;
int FphoneNumber;
String Fname;
ArrayList<Student> students;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Intent intent = getIntent();
students = (ArrayList<Student>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("AddNewStudent");
setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
edit();
addStudent();
}
public void edit() {
name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.StudentName);
phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
final Button addStudent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddStudent);

name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        addStudent.setEnabled(!name.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty());
        Fname = name.getText().toString();

        String phoneNumber = phone.getText().toString();
        FphoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(phoneNumber);
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});
}

public void addStudent() {

add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddStudent);

add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override

    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(AddActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("studentName",name.getText().toString() );
        intent.putExtra("phoneNumber",phone.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);

        Student student = new Student(Fname, FphoneNumber);

        students.add(student);



    }
});
}

public void addStudent(){
add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddStudent);
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(AddActivity.this,Record.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
}
```

Student.java - https://jsfiddle.net/gy0g7b0s/

```
public class Student {

String mName;
int mPhoneNumber;


public Student (String name, int number){
mName = name;
mPhoneNumber = number;
};

public String getmName() {
return mName;
}

public String getmName(String newName) {
return (this.mName = newName);
}

public int getmPhoneNumber() {
return this.mPhoneNumber;
}

public int getmPhoneNumber(int newPhoneNumber) {
return (this.mPhoneNumber = newPhoneNumber);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
return String.format("%s\t%f",this.mName, this.mPhoneNumber);
```

[1] : [Image of Main Activity Page] https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kzmz.jpg

[2] : [Image of Add Activity Page] https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRo3V.jpg

Answer (score 0):

you can store them as `public static variable` or create AddActivity constructor and get functions.

```
String student name; /*add value to this variable @onCreate or wherever in your AddActivity*/

public class AddActivity(/*here to pass data to addactivity*/){
//
}
public String getName(){
return this.name;
}
```

in another activity

```
AddActivity ac = new AddActivity();
String someName = ac.getName();
```

you can use this logic to pass data.

Edit
but if you want to pass data with Intent then just check intenr content onCreate()

```
Intent i = getIntent();
if(i.hasExtra("intentKey")){//check if it s not null
String name = i.getExtraString("intentKay");
}
```

Comment: hello there would you be able to show me the codes that I need?

Comment: check the intent as i edit my answer, hope it helps you ;)

Comment: Hello I am actually trying to add the data via the EditText by clicking the add button in the AddActivity page and trying to show the datas that I have just added into the MainActivity page.

Comment: Static variables in android are bad ideas. Why do you suggest it? Also never explicitly `new` any Activity class

Comment: Yea I actually don't want to use static variables too.

Comment: Hello cricket_007, can u mention in details reason for Why static variables are bad ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could find is, declare that array list as static and you could access those wherever you want provided if the classes are in the same package. But if you want to store those values, used shared preferences. Hope this may helps out.

Comment: Hello could you show me how to do it? I am new to android development.

Comment: In AddActivity Class,

declare Arraylist Students As below:

public static ArrayList<Student> students;

Now, use students list wherever you want.

Comment: Hello sorry I still have no idea how to do it. Do you have teamviewer?